# problem with composer install and php version when deploying web app

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp, composer-php

I need to deploy a web application written with Laravel and vue.js.
The server is on AWS with ubuntu 18.04.
Initially the development was done on a windows machine with Xampp v7.4.10, Control Panel v3.2.4 and with PHP v7.4.10.
Later I developed on a macOs machine with the same version of Xampp and with PHP v7.4.28.
I found out that I have PHP v7.3.18 on the server and when I tried to run the command

```
composer install
```

gives me this error:

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for psr/container 1.1.2 -> satisfiable by psr/container[1.1.2].
    - psr/container 1.1.2 requires php >=7.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - psr/container 1.1.2 requires php >=7.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.18) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/service-contracts v2.5.0 requires psr/container ^1.1 -> satisfiable by psr/container[1.1.2].
    - Installation request for symfony/service-contracts v2.5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/service-contracts[v2.5.0].
```

I installed and enabled PHP v7.4 using the following shell commands:

```
    sudo apt install php7.4
    sudo a2dismod php7.3
    sudo a2enmod php7.4
    sudo systemctl restart apache2
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

but now it gives me this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/gd2 (/usr/lib/php/20190902/gd2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/gd2.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/gd2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'bz2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for nikic/php-parser v4.13.2 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v4.13.2].
    - nikic/php-parser v4.13.2 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for psy/psysh v0.11.1 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.11.1].
    - psy/psysh v0.11.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.4 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.4].
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for phar-io/manifest 2.0.3 -> satisfiable by phar-io/manifest[2.0.3].
    - phar-io/manifest 2.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter v0.5 -> satisfiable by php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter[v0.5].
    - php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter v0.5 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.15 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[7.0.15].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.15 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-token-stream 4.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-token-stream[4.0.4].
    - phpunit/php-token-stream 4.0.4 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.5.23 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.23].
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.23 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 9
    - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.2.1 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.2.1].
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 10
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.20.44 requires tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles ^2.2.1 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.4].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v6.20.44 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.20.44].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

But now i don't know how to go about trying to fix this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO, check the composer version on your local machine and then on online

Comment: You have to install the missing extensions. Try to install php7.4-common, php7.4-xml...